# Github Enterprise - Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, github-enterprise

I'm trying to get the post-commit hooks for github enterprise to talk to our internal jenkins server.  Been trying for the last several hours and haven't been able to get it working.

What I was able to do is get the github enterprise webhook with url:

```
http://192.168.10.123:8080/job/Github%20Build%20Test/build
```

working to kick off a build.

I'm not able to authenticate with github enterprise using either the basic authentication or oauth2 authentication tokens.[image: Authentication Settings]

Also with manual setup it doesn't seem to work either.  Any ideas / help?

Comment: Is your problem that github enterprise cannot access Jenkins or that Jenkins cannot pull from github enterprise? Your screenshot shows the webhook setup from Jenkins but your text above mentions that github can start a build using a webhook - why include a screenshot of the part that you just described as working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to wait for v1.41 of the Jenkins [GitHub API plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+API+Plugin)

See this [pull request](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/pull/52)